# Linking Activities Using Intents (Android Beginner)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm beginning to learn Android and have been reading the "Beginning Android 4 Application Development." (As well as downloading the relevant source code)..

However; I have been trying to create a very simple slideshow with a button labelled "Gallery" which will take me to a new Activity that will show a grid like layout for my photos. However, my application does not do this. When the button is pressed it either crashes the app or refuses to do anything at all.

***Manifest***

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="Viwer"
        android:name=".Viwer" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.viwer.Gallery" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I assume it's something simple but after looking at it for three hours I can't see what it is.

Comment: can you post the Logcat output here?

Comment: What is the name of your gallery activity? is it Viwer or Gallery?

Comment: The project is named Viwer and the activity is named Gallery.java

Comment: Sorry I'm having problems copying it in, but heres the last few lines. Think I found the prob.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.viwer.Viwer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.viwer-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.viwer-1, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Gallery activity to the Android Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".Gallery"
    android:label="Gallery"></activity>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that is still resulting in a force close.

EDIT// I replaced Viewr with Gallery and it is working. Thanks so much!

Comment: in your Main_Activity try: 
    `startActivity(new Intent(this, Gallery.class);`

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you register viewer activity in an intent-filter yet is not declare as a broadcast receiver.

Second event if it was a broadcast receiver it will never launch as you do not send any broadcast by calling startActivity

i think that what your trying to achieve is this:

Please try this:

```
 ebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,Viwer.calss )
            startActivity(intent);
            }

    });
```